# Prevent LyX from creating new paragraphs after float

Tags: floats, lyx, line-breaking, paragraphs, tufte-book

Using LyX with tufte-book class, whenever I insert a margin figure, LyX creates a new paragraph. Same for colored boxes. Can this be suppressed somehow?

Comment: Excuse me very much but I have only the guide in MAC in Italian language.

Comment: It is not the fault of LyX,  the `marginfigure` environment in `tufte-book` use the macro `\FloatBarrier` internally. The macro `\FloatBarrier` starts a new paragraph.

Comment: @UdiFogiel I have cited the \FloatBarrier in the addendum.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I wanted to add that `marginfigure` use `\FloatBarrier`.

Comment: @UdiFogiel I hope it has been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time we type ENTER, LYX in addition to sending a carriage return to the text starts a new paragraph.
Place the mouse where we want to wrap and select on the menu bar the
"Insert" item and on the drop-down menu that opens place the mouse over "Formatting."

Another drop-down menu will open: select "Simple carriage return."

[image]

The following label will appear in the document:

[image]

Or place the mouse where we want to head to insert the corresponding TeX code by selecting the "Insert TeX Code" button:

[image]

A small red rectangle called the ERT box will open. Enter the TeX code we want in the ERT box. In our case in the ERT box we write the command to wrap:

[image]

Whichever method is chosen, the text will wrap without starting a new paragraph.

**Addendum 1/8/2023**:

The `Tufte-LaTeX` document classes automatically include the `placeins`
package. This package provides the `\FloatBarrier` command. If you put
the `\FloatBarrier` command in your document, it will force LaTeX to
process all of the floats before typesetting any more material. (This
also has the side-effect of starting a new paragraph, so use it
between paragraphs.) I've attached a short example document that
illustrates the effect of the `\FloatBarrier` command (along with using
the `morefloats` package).

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{morefloats}

\title{Many Sidenotes}

\begin{document}

This\sidenote{First} 
document\sidenote{Second} 
tests\sidenote{Third} 
how\sidenote{Fourth} 
many\sidenote{Fifth} 
sidenotes\sidenote{Sixth} 
can\sidenote{Seventh} 
be\sidenote{Eighth} 
accumulated\sidenote{Ninth} 
\FloatBarrier% immediately causes all previous floats to be processed before continuing
in\sidenote{Tenth} 
a\sidenote{Eleventh} 
short\sidenote{Twelth} 
space\sidenote{Thirteenth} 
before\sidenote{Fourteenth} 
\LaTeX{}\sidenote{Fifteenth} 
panics\sidenote{Sixteenth} 
and\sidenote{Seventeenth} 
\FloatBarrier% immediately causes all previous floats to be processed before continuing
complains\sidenote{Eighteenth} 
about\sidenote{Nineteenth} 
too\sidenote{Twentieth} 
many\sidenote{Twenty-first} 
unprocessed\sidenote{Twenty-second} 
floats.\sidenote{Twenty-third}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is, after, a recent guide of LyX where to pag. 17 there is the argument of the paragraph. Here there is the link. I used LyX 16 years ago.

http://ftp.lyx.de/Documentation/en/UserGuide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, this doesn't solve the problem. If I insert a float MarginFigure, LyX creates a new paragraph anyway. And if I try to place the break after the float, it gives error "there is no line to end". I want to insert a marginfigure without any line break.

Comment: @kobaltishblue_312 I have done of my best. See new addendum. Best regards.